# Fedex Shipping not showing on the Magento Website Frontend

Tags: magento

I have recently configured a magento website with fedex shipping. But it is not showing on the frontend.

1. I have added the origin in shipping settings
2. I have properly configured the fedex shipping with proper Account id, meter number, key and password.
3. All my products has weights.

What else the issue can be? Do I need to configure the table rates shipping to make fedex work? I just cannot make out what the issue can be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a programming-related Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead?